# Attempting to make a function in C++ in someone else's code (A* Search)

Tags: c++, function

I took code from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-search-algorithm/ to see if I could make a function out of the cell destination part of the code. As I'm still fairly new to programming, I have, as expected, run into some difficulties. When I try to run my borrowed code, I get the errors shown below. Also below is the original code, and my attempt at a function. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**THE ERRORS**

```
In function 'void aStarSearch(int (*)[10], Pair, Pair):
invalid conversion from 'int (*)[10]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
could not convert 'j' from 'int' to 'Pair {aka std::pair<int, int>}
```

**THE ORIGINAL:**

```
// A C++ Program to implement A* Search Algorithm
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define ROW 9
#define COL 10

// Creating a shortcut for int, int pair type
typedef pair<int, int> Pair;

// Creating a shortcut for pair<int, pair<int, int>> type
typedef pair<double, pair<int, int> > pPair;

// A structure to hold the neccesary parameters
struct cell
{
    // Row and Column index of its parent
    // Note that 0 <= i <= ROW-1 & 0 <= j <= COL-1
    int parent_i, parent_j;
    // f = g + h
    double f, g, h;
};

// A Utility Function to check whether given cell (row, col)
// is a valid cell or not.
bool isValid(int row, int col)
{
    // Returns true if row number and column number
    // is in range
    return (row >= 0) && (row < ROW) &&
        (col >= 0) && (col < COL);
}

// A Utility Function to check whether the given cell is
// blocked or not
bool isUnBlocked(int grid[][COL], int row, int col)
{
    // Returns true if the cell is not blocked else false
    if (grid[row][col] == 1)
        return (true);
    else
        return (false);
}

// A Utility Function to check whether destination cell has
// been reached or not
bool isDestination(int row, int col, Pair dest)
{
    if (row == dest.first && col == dest.second)
        return (true);
    else
        return (false);
}

// A Utility Function to calculate the 'h' heuristics.
double calculateHValue(int row, int col, Pair dest)
{
    // Return using the distance formula
    return ((double)sqrt ((row-dest.first)*(row-dest.first)
                        + (col-dest.second)*(col-dest.second)));
}

// A Utility Function to trace the path from the source
// to destination
void tracePath(cell cellDetails[][COL], Pair dest)
{
    printf ("\nThe Path is ");
    int row = dest.first;
    int col = dest.second;

    stack<Pair> Path;

    while (!(cellDetails[row][col].parent_i == row
            && cellDetails[row][col].parent_j == col ))
    {
        Path.push (make_pair (row, col));
        int temp_row = cellDetails[row][col].parent_i;
        int temp_col = cellDetails[row][col].parent_j;
        row = temp_row;
        col = temp_col;
    }

    Path.push (make_pair (row, col));
    while (!Path.empty())
    {
        pair<int,int> p = Path.top();
        Path.pop();
        printf("-> (%d,%d) ",p.first,p.second);
    }

    return;
}

// A Function to find the shortest path between
// a given source cell to a destination cell according
// to A* Search Algorithm
void aStarSearch(int grid[][COL], Pair src, Pair dest)
{
    // If the source is out of range
    if (isValid (src.first, src.second) == false)
    {
        printf ("Source is invalid\n");
        return;
    }

    // If the destination is out of range
    if (isValid (dest.first, dest.second) == false)
    {
        printf ("Destination is invalid\n");
        return;
    }

    // Either the source or the destination is blocked
    if (isUnBlocked(grid, src.first, src.second) == false ||
            isUnBlocked(grid, dest.first, dest.second) == false)
    {
        printf ("Source or the destination is blocked\n");
        return;
    }

    // If the destination cell is the same as source cell
    if (isDestination(src.first, src.second, dest) == true)
    {
        printf ("We are already at the destination\n");
        return;
    }

    // Create a closed list and initialise it to false which means
    // that no cell has been included yet
    // This closed list is implemented as a boolean 2D array
    bool closedList[ROW][COL];
    memset(closedList, false, sizeof (closedList));

    // Declare a 2D array of structure to hold the details
    //of that cell
    cell cellDetails[ROW][COL];

    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<ROW; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<COL; j++)
        {
            cellDetails[i][j].f = FLT_MAX;
            cellDetails[i][j].g = FLT_MAX;
            cellDetails[i][j].h = FLT_MAX;
            cellDetails[i][j].parent_i = -1;
            cellDetails[i][j].parent_j = -1;
        }
    }

    // Initialising the parameters of the starting node
    i = src.first, j = src.second;
    cellDetails[i][j].f = 0.0;
    cellDetails[i][j].g = 0.0;
    cellDetails[i][j].h = 0.0;
    cellDetails[i][j].parent_i = i;
    cellDetails[i][j].parent_j = j;

    /*
    Create an open list having information as-
    <f, <i, j>>
    where f = g + h,
    and i, j are the row and column index of that cell
    Note that 0 <= i <= ROW-1 & 0 <= j <= COL-1
    This open list is implenented as a set of pair of pair.*/
    set<pPair> openList;

    // Put the starting cell on the open list and set its
    // 'f' as 0
    openList.insert(make_pair (0.0, make_pair (i, j)));

    // We set this boolean value as false as initially
    // the destination is not reached.
    bool foundDest = false;

    while (!openList.empty())
    {
        pPair p = *openList.begin();

        // Remove this vertex from the open list
        openList.erase(openList.begin());

        // Add this vertex to the open list
        i = p.second.first;
        j = p.second.second;
        closedList[i][j] = true;

    /*
        Generating all the 8 successor of this cell

            N.W N N.E
            \ | /
            \ | /
            W----Cell----E
                / | \
            / | \
            S.W S S.E

        Cell-->Popped Cell (i, j)
        N --> North  (i-1, j)
        S --> South  (i+1, j)
        E --> East   (i, j+1)
        W --> West       (i, j-1)
        N.E--> North-East (i-1, j+1)
        N.W--> North-West (i-1, j-1)
        S.E--> South-East (i+1, j+1)
        S.W--> South-West (i+1, j-1)*/

        // To store the 'g', 'h' and 'f' of the 8 successors
        double gNew, hNew, fNew;

        //----------- 1st Successor (North) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid(i-1, j) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i-1, j, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i-1][j].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i-1][j].parent_j = j;
                printf ("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath (cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }
            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i-1][j] == false &&
                    isUnBlocked(grid, i-1, j) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.0;
                hNew = calculateHValue (i-1, j, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //           OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i-1][j].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i-1][j].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair(fNew,
                                            make_pair(i-1, j)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i-1][j].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 2nd Successor (South) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid(i+1, j) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i+1, j, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i+1][j].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i+1][j].parent_j = j;
                printf("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath(cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }
            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i+1][j] == false &&
                    isUnBlocked(grid, i+1, j) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.0;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i+1, j, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //           OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i+1][j].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i+1][j].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair (fNew, make_pair (i+1, j)));
                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i+1][j].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 3rd Successor (East) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid (i, j+1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i, j+1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i][j+1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i][j+1].parent_j = j;
                printf("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath(cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i][j+1] == false &&
                    isUnBlocked (grid, i, j+1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.0;
                hNew = calculateHValue (i, j+1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //           OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i][j+1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i][j+1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair(fNew,
                                        make_pair (i, j+1)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i][j+1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j+1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j+1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j+1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i][j+1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 4th Successor (West) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid(i, j-1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i, j-1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i][j-1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i][j-1].parent_j = j;
                printf("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath(cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i][j-1] == false &&
                    isUnBlocked(grid, i, j-1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.0;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i, j-1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //           OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i][j-1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i][j-1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair (fNew,
                                        make_pair (i, j-1)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i][j-1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j-1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j-1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i][j-1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i][j-1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 5th Successor (North-East) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid(i-1, j+1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i-1, j+1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i-1][j+1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i-1][j+1].parent_j = j;
                printf ("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath (cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i-1][j+1] == false &&
                    isUnBlocked(grid, i-1, j+1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.414;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i-1, j+1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //           OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i-1][j+1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i-1][j+1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair (fNew,
                                    make_pair(i-1, j+1)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i-1][j+1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j+1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j+1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j+1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j+1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 6th Successor (North-West) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid (i-1, j-1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination (i-1, j-1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i-1][j-1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i-1][j-1].parent_j = j;
                printf ("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath (cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i-1][j-1] == false &&
                    isUnBlocked(grid, i-1, j-1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.414;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i-1, j-1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //           OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i-1][j-1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i-1][j-1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert( make_pair (fNew, make_pair (i-1, j-1)));
                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i-1][j-1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j-1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j-1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j-1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i-1][j-1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 7th Successor (South-East) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid(i+1, j+1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i+1, j+1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i+1][j+1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i+1][j+1].parent_j = j;
                printf ("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath (cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i+1][j+1] == false &&
                    isUnBlocked(grid, i+1, j+1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.414;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i+1, j+1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //           OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i+1][j+1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i+1][j+1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert(make_pair(fNew,
                                        make_pair (i+1, j+1)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i+1][j+1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j+1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j+1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j+1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j+1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }

        //----------- 8th Successor (South-West) ------------

        // Only process this cell if this is a valid one
        if (isValid (i+1, j-1) == true)
        {
            // If the destination cell is the same as the
            // current successor
            if (isDestination(i+1, j-1, dest) == true)
            {
                // Set the Parent of the destination cell
                cellDetails[i+1][j-1].parent_i = i;
                cellDetails[i+1][j-1].parent_j = j;
                printf("The destination cell is found\n");
                tracePath(cellDetails, dest);
                foundDest = true;
                return;
            }

            // If the successor is already on the closed
            // list or if it is blocked, then ignore it.
            // Else do the following
            else if (closedList[i+1][j-1] == false &&
                    isUnBlocked(grid, i+1, j-1) == true)
            {
                gNew = cellDetails[i][j].g + 1.414;
                hNew = calculateHValue(i+1, j-1, dest);
                fNew = gNew + hNew;

                // If it isn’t on the open list, add it to
                // the open list. Make the current square
                // the parent of this square. Record the
                // f, g, and h costs of the square cell
                //           OR
                // If it is on the open list already, check
                // to see if this path to that square is better,
                // using 'f' cost as the measure.
                if (cellDetails[i+1][j-1].f == FLT_MAX ||
                        cellDetails[i+1][j-1].f > fNew)
                {
                    openList.insert(make_pair(fNew,
                                        make_pair(i+1, j-1)));

                    // Update the details of this cell
                    cellDetails[i+1][j-1].f = fNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j-1].g = gNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j-1].h = hNew;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j-1].parent_i = i;
                    cellDetails[i+1][j-1].parent_j = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // When the destination cell is not found and the open
    // list is empty, then we conclude that we failed to
    // reach the destiantion cell. This may happen when the
    // there is no way to destination cell (due to blockages)
    if (foundDest == false)
        printf("Failed to find the Destination Cell\n");

    return;
}


// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    /* Description of the Grid-
    1--> The cell is not blocked
    0--> The cell is blocked */
    int grid[ROW][COL] =
    {
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 }
    };

    // Source is the left-most bottom-most corner
    Pair src = make_pair(8, 0);

    // Destination is the left-most top-most corner
    Pair dest = make_pair(0, 0);

    aStarSearch(grid, src, dest);

    return(0);
}
```

**MY ATTEMPT:**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define ROW 9
#define COL 10

struct cell{
    int parent_i, parent_j;
    double f, g, h;
};

typedef pair<int, int> Pair;
typedef pair<double, pair<int, int> > pPair;
cell cellDetails[ROW][COL];
set<pPair> openList;
bool foundDest = false;
bool closedList[ROW][COL];
int i, j;

void destCell(int x, int y, Pair dest);

bool isValid(int row, int col){
    return (row >= 0) && (row < ROW) && (col >= 0) && (col < COL);
}

bool isUnBlocked(int grid[][COL], int row, int col){
    if (grid[row][col] == 1)
        return (true);
    else
        return (false);
}

bool isDestination(int row, int col, Pair dest){
    if (row == dest.first && col == dest.second)
        return (true);
    else
        return (false);
}

double calculateHValue(int row, int col, Pair dest){
    return ((double)sqrt ((row-dest.first)*(row-dest.first) + (col-dest.second)*(col-dest.second)));
}

void tracePath(cell cellDetails[][COL], Pair dest){
    printf ("\nThe Path is ");
    int row = dest.first;
    int col = dest.second;
    stack<Pair> Path;

    while (!(cellDetails[row][col].parent_i == row && cellDetails[row][col].parent_j == col )){
        Path.push (make_pair (row, col));
        int temp_row = cellDetails[row][col].parent_i;
        int temp_col = cellDetails[row][col].parent_j;
        row = temp_row;
        col = temp_col;
    }

    Path.push (make_pair (row, col));
    while (!Path.empty()){
        pair<int,int> p = Path.top();
        Path.pop();
        printf("-> (%d,%d) ",p.first,p.second);
    }
    return;
}

void aStarSearch(int grid[][COL], Pair src, Pair dest){
    if (isValid (src.first, src.second) == false){
        printf ("Source is invalid\n");
        return;
    }

    if (isValid (dest.first, dest.second) == false){
        printf ("Destination is invalid\n");
        return;
    }

    if (isUnBlocked(grid, src.first, src.second) == false || isUnBlocked(grid, dest.first, dest.second) == false){
        printf ("Source or the destination is blocked\n");
        return;
    }

    if (isDestination(src.first, src.second, dest) == true){
        printf ("We are already at the destination\n");
        return;
    }

    memset(closedList, false, sizeof (closedList));

    for (i=0; i<ROW; i++){
        for (j=0; j<COL; j++){
            cellDetails[i][j].f = FLT_MAX;
            cellDetails[i][j].g = FLT_MAX;
            cellDetails[i][j].h = FLT_MAX;
            cellDetails[i][j].parent_i = -1;
            cellDetails[i][j].parent_j = -1;
        }
    }

    i = src.first, j = src.second;
    cellDetails[i][j].f = 0.0;
    cellDetails[i][j].g = 0.0;
    cellDetails[i][j].h = 0.0;
    cellDetails[i][j].parent_i = i;
    cellDetails[i][j].parent_j = j;
    openList.insert(make_pair (0.0, make_pair (i, j)));

    while (!openList.empty()){
        pPair p = *openList.begin();
        openList.erase(openList.begin());
        i = p.second.first;
        j = p.second.second;
        closedList[i][j] = true;

        destCell(grid, i-1, j, dest);

      if (foundDest == false)
        printf("Failed to find the Destination Cell\n");
      return;
    }
}
void destCell(int grid[][COL], int x, int y, Pair dest){
  double gNew, hNew, fNew;
  if (isValid(x, y) == true){
    if (isDestination(x, y, dest) == true){
        cellDetails[x][y].parent_i = x;
        cellDetails[x][y].parent_j = y;
        printf ("The destination cell is found\n");
        tracePath (cellDetails, dest);
        foundDest = true;
        return;
    }else if (closedList[x][y] == false && isUnBlocked(grid, x, y) == true){
        gNew = cellDetails[x][y].g + 1.0;
        hNew = calculateHValue (x, y, dest);
        fNew = gNew + hNew;
        if (cellDetails[x][y].f == FLT_MAX || cellDetails[x][y].f > fNew){
            openList.insert( make_pair(fNew, make_pair(x, y)));
            cellDetails[x][y].f = fNew;
            cellDetails[x][y].g = gNew;
            cellDetails[x][y].h = hNew;
            cellDetails[x][y].parent_i = x;
            cellDetails[x][y].parent_j = y;
        }
    }
  }
}

int main(){
    /* Description of the Grid-
    1--> The cell is not blocked
    0--> The cell is blocked */
    int grid[ROW][COL] =
    {
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 },
        { 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0 },
        { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 },
        { 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1 },
        { 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 }
    };

    Pair src = make_pair(8, 0);
    Pair dest = make_pair(0, 0);
    aStarSearch(grid, src, dest);
    return(0);
}
```

**WHERE I THINK THE ERROR IS:**

```
//This call:
destCell(grid, i-1, j, dest);

//To this function:
void destCell(int grid[][COL], int x, int y, Pair dest){
  if (isValid(x, y) == true){
    if (isDestination(x, y, dest) == true){
        cellDetails[x][y].parent_i = x;
        cellDetails[x][y].parent_j = y;
        printf ("The destination cell is found\n");
        tracePath (cellDetails, dest);
        foundDest = true;
        return;
    }else if (closedList[x][y] == false && isUnBlocked(grid, x, y) == true){
        gNew = cellDetails[x][y].g + 1.0;
        hNew = calculateHValue (x, y, dest);
        fNew = gNew + hNew;
        if (cellDetails[x][y].f == FLT_MAX || cellDetails[x][y].f > fNew){
            openList.insert( make_pair(fNew, make_pair(x, y)));
            cellDetails[x][y].f = fNew;
            cellDetails[x][y].g = gNew;
            cellDetails[x][y].h = hNew;
            cellDetails[x][y].parent_i = x;
            cellDetails[x][y].parent_j = y;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Be very careful with the `#include<bits/stdc++.h> using namespace std;` combination. `#include<bits stdc++.h>` includes the entire standard library (in g++. Everywhere else this is an error because this is a g++ internal implementation header, not a standard library header, and is not meant to be used directly). That's a lot of stuff. Tens of thousands of identifiers. `using namespace std;` places everything you include from the standard namespace into the global namespace where it competes with your code. That makes for tens of thousands of potential landmines waiting for you to step on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect function prototype, In the beginning of your code you prototype this function:

```
void destCell(int x, int y, Pair dest);
```

later on you define your function to be

```
void destCell(int grid[][COL], int x, int y, Pair dest)
```

and lastly you use that function like this:

```
destCell(grid, i-1, j, dest);
```

So, just change your function prototype to this:

```
void destCell(int grid[][COL], int x, int y, Pair dest);
```

And everything should compile.

When I compiled, I got this error message:

```
tmp.cpp: In function 'void aStarSearch(int (*)[10], Pair, Pair)':
tmp.cpp:116:36: error: invalid conversion from 'int (*)[10]' to 'int' [-fpermissive]
         destCell(grid, i-1, j, dest);
                                    ^
tmp.cpp:116:36: error: could not convert 'j' from 'int' to 'Pair {aka std::pair<int, int>}'
```

The last line tells me that something is wrong when I try to call the function destCell, I checked the prototype, and the actual function and found the discrepancy